# is it a good idea to create a VLAN for docker containers, and how to do it

Tags: networking, router, docker, unifi

I have a Unifi Dream Router for my network, and a Synology to run my docker containers.

I'm thinking that if I can create separate network for my docker containers; I can correctly setup firewall rules between my IoT devices, my containers and my 'normal' network.
Sadly I don't find much info: I can use macvlan to expose my dockers on my network as separate devices. But this still means they will be in the same network as my Synology.
As such I won't be able to easily make rules on how traffic can flow between my docker containers (f.e. mqtt, homeassistant, zigbee) and IoT devices

Is it possible to force all my docker containers into 1 unifi network?
Is it a good idea to do this?
How would I configure this in docker and in unifi?

Comment: Hi! I answered for any-case. You should mention the model of the NAS, and elaborate on further networking devices like your switch's model and ask if you need further information.

Answer (score 1):

Security is important. IMHO it is great that you invest in it!

To your question - it really depends, but if you have another ethernet port in your Synology, you could use connect it to the switch on another VLAN, then configure the macvlan-lan to use that interface.

If you don't have another port, it'd seem that you can set an alias, but I don't know if it'll play well with macvlan [For more information](https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/17/post/10010). You'll need to set the switchport to "trunk" to pass two VLANs at-once, if it supports that.

You can also run it on another host, like a NUC or an old desktop, and use the storage remotely.

Comment: I'm thinking of having a 'docker'network. If I put the synology on that network, that doesn't solve the issue as other services run there too.
I think now my question is not feasible as Unify segments based on physical port or wifi-network. I can't find a way to assign a vlan in another way (I still have to investigate Radius)

Comment: @Brtrnd RADIUS just forward identification request and shouldn't be relevant to this kind of networking. As I said, You can run two IP-addresses off the same switchport, if it supports TRUNK. You still haven't mentioned the models of your switch and NAS.

Comment: Basically.... when a port is set to "access" then it can only access one specific VLAN, but "trunk" allows you to run several VLANS along the same port ( like, when you connect a second switch to that port, and it suppose to run several VLANs ). Am I clear? haha sorry English isn't my first language haha

Comment: The main difference between you and me, is that I joined my NAS in my "Servers" vlan, allowing me to run dockers off the same network, and not having to deal with your problem. ( Also, my NAS is my old PC, so I can have as many NICs as I want to haha )